# MySql List all items from table 1 where item conditionally exists in table 2

Tags: php, mysql

Table-1 `parts` is a full parts catalog. Primary index field is `PartID` (int, auto-increment).

Table-2 `inventory` is a list of partIDs connected to various distributors. Important fields are DistID and PartID. Primary index field is `InvID` (int, auto-increment).

In Table-2, there will be a unique entry (InvID) for each part a distributor has, so many duplicate DistID/PartID entries.

Given a particular `DistID`, I must first get a list of all `PartID`s associated with that `DistID` (inventory Table-2), and then `SELECT * FROM parts` (Table-1) for all those `PartID`s.

The end result set is a list of all part information (T1) for each unique part held by a distributor (T2).

I'd like to do this using a single mysql query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is to start with a distinct list of the `inventory` for that distributor. This is our base query (replace the question mark with your actual distributor ID):
`SELECT DISTINCT partID FROM inventory WHERE DistID = ?`

Then we modify that query to join on the `parts` table to pull back the part information:

`SELECT DISTINCT i.partID, p.* FROM inventory i INNER JOIN parts p ON i.partID = p.partID WHERE i.DistID = ?`

Answer (score 2):

thats not a PHP question at all.

Anyway, if I understood your question your should try this:

```
SELECT parts.* FROM parts WHERE parts.PartID IN (SELECT invetory.PartID FROM invetory WHERE invetory.DistID = 'wanted_DistID');
```

You should change 'wanted_DistID' for you wanted DistID. 
Hope I could help.